# Wrong references in research paper

Tags: citations

I came across around 10 wrong references in a medical research paper (still reading). How many citation errors (wrong references) are acceptable? Or: how many wrong references are still ok to be rectified in the erratum section of a journal? Is there a point where there have other actions to be taken? What needs to happen if there are too many reference errors? Thank you

Comment: How are these references "wrong"?

Comment: Agreed. Unclear what's "wrong" with the references. Were the references formatted incorrectly?

Comment: Some are referencing completely unrelated papers, other reference papers that briefly touch on the topic but give no details to the topic at hand and reference again. This looks to me like referencing references if that mkes sense. Other references are books that deal with the general topc. The specifics of the reference, though, is not clear and it looks like I would have to read the whole book to find more specific information to that reference. Is that common practice? Jut to add: I have contacted the author but there was no reply. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question with the clarifications. Comments can disappear.

Comment: A reference to a (text) book that gives general background for a paper is sometimes helpful.

Comment: There is a difference between being irrelevant and being wrong. To prove that the references are wrong, you've to present a solid explanation to that. I also suggest clarifying the question in a broader context with something like: Suppose Paper A talks about Topic A, however the pointed to reference does not entail anything regarding Topic A, so on and so forth!

Answer (score 1):

If "wrong references" are links to papers not supporting the claims made in any sensible way, contact the editorial office. If you are not completely sure about that, reach out to authors first and ask for clarifications.